# Decrement float from 1.0f to 0.0f (C++)

Tags: c++, static, alpha, decrement

I'm trying to set a screen alpha amount from 1.0f to 0.0f (complete fade out). I have the following defined:

```
static float cur_alpha;
```

And the function to do it is named HUD_FadeAlpha. There is also a HUD_SetAlpha, but it only contains {cur_alpha = alpha;}, where FadeAlpha attempts to set alpha and decrement the float to 0.0f:

```
void HUD_FadeAlpha(float alpha)
{
    cur_alpha = alpha;
    int i;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i-- )
    {
      alpha = 1.000f + i/1.000f;
    }

}
```

This is supposed to decrement the alpha value from 1.0f to 0.0f (transparent). It is only to be used with this:

```
void Message_Drawer(void)
{
    CON_ShowFPS();

    if (message_on)
    {
        HUD_SetAlpha(1.000f); // sets the alpha
        HUD_SetAlignment(0, 0);
        HUD_DrawText(160- 3 / 2, 3, w_message.c_str());
        HUD_FadeAlpha();//******** the function to fade out. ********
        HUD_SetScale();
        HUD_SetAlignment();
        HUD_SetAlpha();
        HUD_FadeAlpha();
    }

}
```

But for some reason, it isn't working, it's acting like there isn't anything to decrement, so it just draws the text to screen and disappears without an alpha fading effect. . . (?)

What I'm trying to do is have the message start at 1.0f, and fade out to 0.0f, since HUD_Alpha sets it to solid, and needs to fade to nothing after the message has been drawn to the screen . For some reason, it's not working correctly, so maybe I'm not setting it up right. Not sure if this needs to be done in HUD_FadeAlpha or in Message_Drawer.

So basically, from 1.0f -> 0.75f, 0.5f, 0.25f, 0.0f, but decremented quickly and smoothly, using 3 decimal places. The message is only drawn to the screen for about 4 seconds and disappears (4*TICRATE, 35tics=1s), so it would need to be fast, but not too fast that it doesn't get drawn to the screen in the first place.

Thank you all so much!! <3

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 100; i-- )....  Do you mean i++?

Comment: Performance note: Worth making a 100 element array and iterating that rather than computing a whack of floating point math every time.

Comment: you dont change `cur_alpha` in the function, but only `alpha` which is the parameter passed to the function

Comment: right now your for loop doesn't do anything because nothing is modified besides `alpha` so the only effect of the loop is equivalent to `alpha = 100.00f`

Comment: also why `i/1.000f`? that doesn't seem to be doing anything helpful

Comment: And why `1.000f` rather than `1.0f`, or even just `1.0`?

Comment: @user4581301 it's worth profiling your code and actually finding out where the hotspots are before optimizing random stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is the following loop:

```
for (int i = 100; i >= 0; i--) {
    alpha = i/100.0f;
    // code here to update the displayed alpha
}
```

Dividing by `1.000f` is just dividing by 1, which doesn't do anyting except convert from `int` to `float`. Dividing by `100.0f` will correctly generate a fraction that decrements each time -- the starting value is `100/100.0f = 1.0f`, and the ending value is `0/100.0f = 0.0f`.

And you need to update the display within the loop, otherwise you'll only see the final alpha value, not the smooth fade. You should probably also have a delay in the loop, so it doesn't go so quickly that the user can't see the fade.

Answer (score 3):

The code to fade out is very wrong:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i-- )
{
    alpha = 1.000f + i/1.000f;
}
```

to start with, you're starting at 0 and decrementing, which means you'll only ever get values of `i = 0`.

Secondly (assuming you fix that issue), on each iteration, you'll get alpha values that look like this:

```
1.000f
2.000f
3.000f
4.000f
5.000f
6.000f
/*...*/
```

And finally, the use of a loop doesn't even make much sense: you'll need to interpolate based on time values, so it should be calculating the alpha value at a given time point.

```
float calculate_alpha(float now, float start_time, float end_time, float start_alpha, float end_alpha) {
    if(now <= start_time) return start_alpha;
    if(now >= end_time) return end_alpha;
    float time_percentage = (now - start_time) / (end_time - start_time);
    return (end_alpha - start_alpha) * time_percentage + start_alpha;
}
```

Which can then be invoked in your host code like so:

```
HUD_setAlpha(calculate_alpha(now, /*time that the fade starts*/, /*time that the fade ends*/, 1, 0));
```

Comment: Okay! I added the calculate_alpha float, but do I also need to change the HUD_SetAlpha function? All I did, since SetAlpha is used elsewhere, is just duplicated it for FadeAlpha. Right now it looks like this:

void HUD_FadeAlpha(float alpha)
{
 cur_alpha = alpha;
}

Where would I shoehorn calculate_alpha into it? Sorry for the noobish question, I really appreciate the help though!! =)

For the "now" float, all I did was use float now = I_GetTime(), which gets the current time that increases over time (35tics/second).